# use a line integral to find the area enclosed by the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{4^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{3^2}=1$

Tags: calculus

A hint is that the area is $$A= \dfrac12(-y\,\mathrm dx+x\,\mathrm dy)$$

I have tried to solve this with no luck. Please Help!

Comment: Your question would get more attention if you showed some of those unsuccessful attempts. I dare say the answers would be more useful to you than someone simply feeding you a solution since then the answers could point out where you’re going wrong or give you that extra bit that you’re missing so that you can solve it for yourself. Please keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 3):

The ellipse can be parametrized as

$$x=4\cos(t)$$
$$y=3\sin(t)$$

with $$0\le t \le 2\pi$$

$$dx=-4\sin(t)dt$$
and
$$dy=3\cos(t)dt$$
thus

$$A=\frac 12\int_0^{2\pi}(-ydx+xdy)$$
$$=\frac 12 \int_0^{2\pi}(12\sin^2(t)+12\cos^2(t))dt$$
$$=12\pi$$